# Malformed S3 policy from Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, policy, terraform-provider-aws

Looks like I'm getting a malformed policy as part of my Terraform deployment and am not seeing any issue(s) with it while looking it over, all the `Principals` seem to be in place and nothing looks *out of the ordinary*. Can someone pick out why this policy is being considered malformed?

Here's the TF output that is throwing

```
module.s3-bucket.aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Creating...
  bucket: "" => "the_s3_bucket"
  policy: "" => "{\n  \"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\n    \"Statement\":[{\n      \"Principal\": \"*\",\n      \"Action\":[\n        \"s3:GetBucketLocation\",\n        \"s3:ListAllMyBuckets\"\n      ],\n        \"Resource\":[\n          \"arn:aws:s3:::*\"\n      ],\n    \"Effect\":\"Allow\"\n  }, {\n    \"Principal\": \"*\",\n    \"Action\":[\n      \"s3:ListBucket\",\n      \"s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads\"\n    ],\n    \"Resource\":[\n      \"arn:aws:s3:::the_s3_bucket\"\n    ],\n    \"Effect\":\"Allow\"\n    }, {\n      \"Principal\": \"*\",\n    \"Action\":[\n      \"s3:GetObject\",\n      \"s3:AbortMultipartUpload\",\n      \"s3:ListMultipartUploadParts\",\n      \"s3:DeleteObject\",\n      \"s3:PutObject\",\n      \"s3:GetObjectAcl\",\n      \"s3:PutObjectAcl\"\n    ],\n    \"Resource\":[\n      \"arn:aws:s3:::the_s3_bucket/*\"\n    ],\n    \"Effect\":\"Allow\"\n  }]\n}\n"
```

The (non-verbose)    Error:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.s3-bucket.aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid action
    status code: 400, request id: DCAEB510D9FE431C, host id: FwZ187PM8RKZljAZGo1578UvsgW3kwtZpaI2Mom46lu7Jr+NV9Jum8txjsfwdJw0jm9ct0awRWk=
```

Here's a *pretty print* of what it contains

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":[
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
        "Resource":[
          "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ],
    "Effect":"Allow"
  }, {
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action":[
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
    ],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::the_s3_bucket"
    ],
    "Effect":"Allow"
    }, {
      "Principal": "*",
    "Action":[
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
      "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObjectAcl",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    ],
    "Resource":[
      "arn:aws:s3:::the_s3_bucket/*"
    ],
    "Effect":"Allow"
  }]
}
```

**Update**

So evidently this has something to do with the `Principal` field, after running this through AWS Console I get the error

```
This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies
```

Comment: Is it valid to have `Principal` in there?  I tend to find using the IAM policy editor helps here - if you paste the above into it, it should help track down what's wrong.  Additionally, you can use the first tab to build your policy, then switch to the json tab to copy it out to use in Terraform.

Comment: `Principal` is fine for bucket policies but not for IAM policies (except for assume role policies... sigh...). You should use the actual bucket policy editor to test and not the closely related IAM policy editor which uses a similar syntax but is actually different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission cannot be applied to an S3 bucket policy and instead is an IAM policy permission. You must also directly specify the bucket that the policy is attached to in the bucket policy rather than use `"Resource": ["*"]` or some other wildcard for the bucket.

IAM policies and S3 bucket policies are closely related and overlap heavily but you should consider them as a further level of control that can sometimes be necessary. Unfortunately the S3 permissions model is very confusing and has multiple layers of adding access control, from [bucket ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) and object ACLs (including fully configurable ones and canned ones) to [bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) and also straight [IAM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html) that are attached to an IAM user or role.

Most of the time you are going to be best off using the [canned ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) and then use IAM user policies to control who can perform extra actions not allowed by the ACL. There's further explanation of these in the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html).